# counting the number of antichains in $P_{m,n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

Define m and n be integers. $P_{m,n}$ denote the set of pairs of integers
$(i,j)$ with $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$. Define a partial order on $P_{m,n}$ as:
\begin{equation}
(i,j)\leq (i^{'},j^{'}) \iff (i\leq i^{'} and \  j\leq j^{'})
\end{equation} 
I've done the first part as "count the number of maximal chains in $P_{m,n}$", but I don't know how to count the number of the antichains in $P_{m,n}$(As it needs to count every size!).
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you write the count as a sum of counts of antichains of size $k$? I don't know if there'll be a nice closed-form for the sum, though.

Comment: @pjs36 Using all sizes seems very hard, as there are $mn$ elements in total, and there are not very useful results that I can use to specify in a particular size $k$ (Or maybe it is because I dont know them lol).

Comment: @bof it sounds great in my first glance, I will try it by induction to see if it is correct, thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following are equal:

(1) the number of antichains in $P_{m,n}$;
(2) the number of [lower sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) in $P_{m,n}$
(3) the number of nondecreasing functions $f:\{1,\dots,m\}\to\{0,1,\dots,n\}$
(4) the number of solutions of the equation $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n=m$ in integers $x_i\ge0$;
(5) the binomial coefficient $\binom{m+n}n$.

(1) = (2): In any finite partially ordered set, the number of antichains is equal to the number of lower sets. If $L$ is a lower set, the set $a(L)$ of all maximal elements of $L$ is an antichain; if $A$ is an antichain, the set $\ell(A)=\{x:\exists a\in A\ (x\in a)\}$ is a lower set; the maps $a$ and $\ell$ are easily seen to be inverses.

(2) = (3): A lower set $L$ corresponds to the function $f(i)=|\{j:(i,j)\in L\}|.$

(3) = (4): A sequence $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ of nonnegative integers with $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n=m$ corresponds to the unique nondecreasing function $f:\{1,\dots,m\}\to\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ such that $|\{i:f(i)=k\}|=x_k$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n.$

(4) = (5): this is the so-called [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) theorem.

Comment: Got the idea, thx!